# Iam using android studio and firestore. In my application when admin adds details it is successfully added but it doesn't shows when user logins

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This code is used to retrieve data from Firestore and the user can see it but it displays nothing other than the hint given.

```
package com.example.e_computerservices;

public class Viewtesting extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView name,email,phoneno;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    String userId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewtesting);
        name=findViewById(R.id.Name);
        email=findViewById(R.id.Email);
        phoneno=findViewById(R.id.PhoneNo);

        fAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        userId=fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DocumentReference documentReference=fStore.collection("Users").document(userId);
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(Viewtesting.this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                name.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Name"));
                email.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("UserEmail"));
                phoneno.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("PhoneNumber"));
            }
        });


    }
}
```

after updating default hint only displays:
[screenshot of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5wMC.jpg)

Database:

[image: database structure]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Sure, you can use [imgbb.com](https://imgbb.com/).

Comment: I have updated please check it

Comment: I got it. I'll write an answer right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem for not displaying the data is the naming of the fields in the database. To solve, please change the following lines of code:

```
name.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Name"));
email.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("UserEmail"));
phoneno.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("PhoneNumber"));
```

To:

```
name.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("name"));
email.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("userEmail"));
phoneno.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("phoneNumber"));
```

See, all properties should start with lower letters, **not** with capital letters. Remember, that you should get the data according to the properties that exist in the database.